# Image map with links to other tabs

Tags: spotfire

I Have an image for a homepage screen. The top part of the image when clicked should lead to the second tab, the left hand side of the image when clicked goes to the third tab and so on.
Basically geotagging an image , so that i can make areas of the image clickable leading to different tabs

I tried implementing using a map chart where i added an image layer, and added this image. Some solutions asked me to add a marker layer with x,y coordinates but I'm unsure on how to proceed on my image
Kindly help with any alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you want an image map. "geo tagging" is when geographic info like latitude and longitude are added to an image.

your best bet is to use a text area with a table filled with image-type action controls. if you have Photoshop, you can use a technique called [Image Slicing](http://www.absolutecross.com/tutorials/photoshop/image-slicing) to prepare your images.

FYI, this is probably not a simple task, especially if you don't know much about HTML. you may want to consider a different navigation scheme.

if you update your question with more detail about the end result you are trying to achieve, maybe someone can share a more fitting solution. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem